# XPath to identify text in html

Tags: html, xpath, xmllint

I have the following structure in an HTML document:

```
<li>
<b>fixed_keyword:</b> varying_text</li>
```

I want to get the `varying_text` part to print with `xmllint`. I have tried

```
xmllint --html --xpath "(//li[/b[text()='fixed_keyword:']]/text())"
xmllint --html --xpath "(//li)/b[text()='fixed_keyword:']/text()"
xmllint --html --xpath "(//li[text()='fixed_keyword:'])/text()"
```

and many more but nothing has worked so far.

What is the correct xpath expression to print `varying_text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis:

```
//li/b[. = 'fixed_keyword:']/following-sibling::text()
```

Note that you don't have `:` in the input HTML.

Comment: Is it possible to remove the leading space in ` varying_text` with via xpath and xmllint? I could run it through `sed` but I would prefer it done with just one command if possible.

Comment: @nautical yeah, you can try with "normalize space": `normalize-space(//li/b[. = 'fixed_keyword:']/following-sibling::text())`.